# Git abortando um checkout

Tags: git, versionamento

Estou tentando pular de branch mas o *git* está abortando a operação.

Estou no branch **dev** tentando ir para o branch **master** :

`$ git checkout master`

Erro:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
.env
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Mas ao verificar minha área de trabalho não encontro nada `$ git status`:

```
No ramo dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'dev/master'.

nada a submeter, diretório de trabalho vazio
```

Como também tento fazer um `$ git stash`:

```
 No local changes to save
```

Tentei utilizar o `git checkout -f master` mas não funcionou:

```
 error: Entry '.env' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

**Observação**: Inicialmente o arquivo *.env* estava no *.gitignore*, só que para poder enviar para um repositório remoto tive que retirá-lo. Então fiz o `git push` que precisava, fui no *.gitignore* novamente o adicionei e fiz um `git update-index --assume-unchanged .env` para retirá-lo do versionamento.

Comment: Acho que poderia utilizar o `git checkout -f master`. Mas não sei se é o ideal.

Comment: Você consegue recuperar o estado deste arquivo de acordo com o git?

git checkout .env

Se conseguir, commita ele, e depois tenta mudar de branch. Se não, cria um arquivo dummy com o mesmo nome '.env' commita e tenta.

Comment: Olá @rafaels88, como faço para recuperar? E pq/oq faz desse comando `git checkout .env`?

Comment: O git checkout .env vai recuperar o estado deste arquivo referente ao branch que você estiver. Se você quiser voltar o estado de um arquivo, ou seja, pegar ele na forma que ele está pushado, basta fazer um checkout no arquivo. A questão é que o GIT deve ter perdido a referencia deste arquivo. Talvez você tenha removido ele com o comando 'rm', deveria ter feito com 'git rm'.

Comment: Acho que entendi @rafaels88. Estava trabalhando no **branch master**, passei para o **branch dev**, fiz alguns commits, um deles foi acessar o meu *.gitignore* e retirar a linha do *.env*,dai dei um `$git push dev dev:master`. Depois disso fui novamente no meu *.gitignore*  adicionei novamente o *.env*, depois o retirei do versionamento com o comando `git update-index --assume-unchanged .env` e fim. Agora só quero voltar para o **branch master** com `$git checkout master` para fazer um `git rebase dev` sem que o arquivo *.env* seja versionado e comitado.  Compreende?

Comment: Entendo sim, mas acho que você deveria voltar o .env primeiro, pro GIT parar de dar esse erro. Commita esse arquivo, pusha ele, e o GIt vai parar de reclamar. Depois disso, você dá um 'git rm' nesse arquivo.

Comment: Showw. Fiz isso que você falou e deu certo.Brigadão @rafaels88!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15221/discussion-between-augustoppimenta-and-rafaels88).

Comment: Que bom, cara! De nada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com grande ajuda de @rafaels88, conseguimos solucionar:

1. Primeiro fiz um `git checkout .env`
2. Depois `git rm .env`
3. Por fim `git commit -m"..."`